# Why is the derivative of $\{x\}$ the graph of $y=1$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, proof-explanation

So  I have been taking interest in the fractional part of $x$ function $y=\{x\}$. Now here's what the fractional part of $x$ is generally defined as:$$\{x\}:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$$which when you plug this into Desmos, it is apparent that this is the graph of$$y=x\pmod1$$Now, here's the thing: When the derivative of the fractional part of $x$ function is taken, it appears that the graph just then is the graph of$$y=1$$

---

## My question:

---

Why would this be? I honestly am unsure why the derivative of the fractional part of $x$ would be the graph of $y=1$, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your function is indeed $x \mod 1$, and is differentiable everywhere but in integers. If $x$ is not an integer, locally, $f(x) = x-n$ for $n = floor(x)$ so $f' = 1$. So your graph is esentalli $y=1$ with small holes at every integer

Comment: Indeed, it is not continuous at the integers and so cannot be differentiable there.

Comment: The function is piecewise linear, and the derivative of a linear function is the slope. All the pieces of the graph have slope $1$. The derivative is not defined at integers, though, so there are "holes" in the graph, unlike $y=1$ proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is differentiable at all points other than the integers, and is not differentiable at the integers.

At all points where the function is differentiable, the derivative is 1, as the function is equal to $f(x) = x-n$ for $n \leq x < n + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Desmos is **not** showing you the graph of $y = 1$, as you can see if you try clicking and dragging along the graph of the function:

[image]  [image]

What we are actually seeing is the graph of a function that is equal to $1$ **except at integer values of $x$**, where it is undefined.